# Updating rows in a DataGrid asynchronously in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, datagrid

I'm very new to ASP.NET WebForms applications. I have an application using a DataGrid which has a DataBinding to a List of objects. When the page loaded completely, I want to add further information to each row in the DataGrid.

The process which determines the additional information for each row must run on the server side and takes about 2s per row (network access etc.). Therefore I would like my DataGrid to refresh after every row has been processed.

This means, that I want an asynchronous mechanism that loads the data while the web page is completely accessible for the user and updates the UI as soon as a row is processed on the server side.

Technically that means that I need to send a HTTP response after processing each row to the client. The client will then read the HTTP response and update the UI.

I already tried using a UpdatePanel with a ScriptManager according to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386452%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#ManagingTriggersProgrammatically).

The problem with this solution is, that the UI updates when the last row has been processed. This is too late. We need an UI update after each row.

I'm used to work with WPF desktop applications. In a WPF desktop application I would just use a background worker. In the ProgressReported-EventHandler I would update the Grid with the new information and invoke an IPropertyChanged notification.

How can I achieve that in ASP.NET (.NET 4.0)? Any help and web resources are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an Ajax query and a WebService

place an import in your head tag

```
<script src="...../js/jquery.ajaxq-0.0.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and place a script zone at the end of the apsx page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<ID_GRID_NAME> tr').each(function () {
            //Get customerId Key
            var customerId = $(this).find("td:first").html();
            if (customerId) {
                $.ajaxq("interventionQ", {
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '<WEB_SERVICE_URL>' + customerId,
                    success: function (griddata) {
                       $(this).find("td:last").html('<span class="badge badge-important"></span>');
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the ScriptManager and use jQuery. Create a gridview and then you can grab that with your AJAX success method and append to an HTML table. You can create an empty table (and hide it) on the client side and then get your table rows via AJAX and append them to the table.

```
$.get( "Default.aspx/MethodName", obj, function ( response )
        {
            var content = $( $.parseHTML( response ) ).find("#divWhereYourGridviewIs");

            if ( $( "#div table" ).html() == null ) {
                $( "#divOnClient" ).html( content ); //this will be the first call to get the table

            }
            else {
                var newRow = $( content ).find( "#grd tr" )[1]; //this will be for each additional row, the [1] skips the header and gets the first row. 
                $( "#htmlTable" ).append( newRow );
            }

   } );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a choice between WebForms and MVC, it would be worth looking into MVC. [This CoderProject page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/594150/MVC-Basic-Site-Step-jqGrid-In) is part of a series which has useful information for doing all that you want to do and more. [This page](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/04/jquery-grid-plugins-for-aspnet.html) has links to some WebForms stuff.

Long story short, [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) have a lot of things like this and examples of how to do them.